# Returning a reference from list of base classes returns 'nothing'

Tags: c#, abstract-class, derived-class

I have several 'items' which share similar functionality, hence I derive them all from a base class that defines the common functionality.

Following that, I also want to have specialized lists of these items, hence I derive container-like classes from an abstract base container.

The following code demonstrates my problem.

**Items**

```
public abstract class QAbstractItem 
{
    public int xAbstractMember;
    public QAbstractItem(int a)
    {
        xAbstractMember = a;
    }
}

public class QSingleItem : QAbstractItem
{
    public int xSingleMember;
    public QSingleItem(int s, int a) : base(a)
    {
        xSingleMember = s;
    }
}
```

**Lists**

```
public abstract class QAbstractItemsList 
{
    public List<QAbstractItem> xItems = new List<QAbstractItem>();

    protected void add(QAbstractItem xItem)
    {
        xItems.Add(xItem);
    }

    public void getFirst(QAbstractItem yItem)
    {
        yItem = xItems[0];        // XXX
    }
}

public class QSingleItemsList : QAbstractItemsList
{
    public void add(QSingleItem S) 
    {
        base.add(S);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
 QSingleItemsList xSingleList = new QSingleItemsList();
 xSingleList.add(new QSingleItem(5, 5));

 QSingleItem xFirst = new QSingleItem(0,0);
 xSingleList.getFirst(xFirst);
```

The last line of code *should* (as it is desired by me) contain (5,5) in xFirst. However, it contains (0,0). When the debugger is on line `XXX`, both xItems[0] and yFirst are (5,5). When the code returns to the caller (main), xFirst is (0,0) all of a sudden. Why?

Any help is much appreciated, 
Daniel

Comment: you may use method overloads and pass arguments by ref. for example one overload would be `public void getFirst(ref QSingleItem yItem)`.but still you have to cast inside the overloaded method. but i think its better. `yItem = (QAbstractItem)xItems[0];`

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation of `getFirst` is incorrect. You need to either add either the ref or out keyword to it. The [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword implies the value passed in can be reassigned, and the [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) keyword says the input value is ignored and the result will be assigned there.

`public void getFirst(ref QAbstractItem yItem)`

or

`public void getFirst(out QAbstractItem yItem)`

Then it would get called like this

```
QAbstractItem xFirst = new QSingleItem(0,0);
xSingleList.getFirst(ref xFirst);
```

to get it to work, but really it should be closer to

`public QAbstractItem getFirst()`

Comment: the problem with ref/out is that it does not work with abstract classes, as Thomas Levesque also pointed out. As for `public QAbstractItem getFirst()` in the real application, I need to get a specific pair of QSingleItems, hence I "return them" in the parameters.

Comment: @DanielBencik It would most likely make more sense to return an object that contains the pair of objects than to use `out`/`ref`.

Comment: @DanielBencik You've lost me, getFirst, only gets you 1 thing. Do you mean you want to get them as the type `QSingItem` not as `QAbstractItem`?

Comment: @Sign: Yes, getFirst was written for demo purposes. In reality, I want to have something like `getSomeTwo()`, i.e. I need to return a specifically chosen pair of QSingleItems.\

Comment: @DanielBencik then why not return a `Tuple<QAbstractitem, QAbstractItem>` ? or some other more specific thing that contains both?

Comment: @Sign: The reason for not returning a tuple is that the first returned item is related to a 'Base' electricity futures product, while the second returned item is related to a 'Peak' electricty futures product. Once the pair is returned, the calling code needs to know which part of the pair is the Base/Peak item. With a tuple, I would have to remember that the first item is Base, the second one is Peak, which is .. well, not robust. Or is there a way to name the items in a tuple?\

Comment: @DanielBencik no way to name an item in a tuple that I know of, but you could just make a little class to hold the pair and name them there.

Comment: @Sign: I know. In the end I went for the least amount of code necessary and used your `QAbstractItem xFirst = new QSingleItem(0,0);` Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void getFirst(QAbstractItem yItem)
{
    yItem = xItems[0];        // XXX
}
```

The `yItem` parameter is passed by value (even though it's a reference type; the reference is passed by value). So when you assign a value to yItem, the caller is not affected, because `yItem` only contains a *copy* of the original reference. For this to work, you would need to pass `yItem` by reference:

```
public void getFirst(ref QAbstractItem yItem)
{
    yItem = xItems[0];        // XXX
}
```

However, in this case, you wouldn't be able to call it with an argument of type `QSingleItem`.

---

An alternative solution to your problem would be to make the list class generic:

```
public class QItemsList<TItem> where TItem : QAbstractItem
{
    public List<TItem> xItems = new List<TItem>();

    protected void add(TItem xItem)
    {
        xItems.Add(xItem);
    }

    public void getFirst(out TItem yItem)
    {
        yItem = xItems[0];        // XXX
    }
}
```

If you need specialized methods for a given type of item, you can add them in a class that inherits the generic list:

```
public class QSingleItemsList : QItemsList<QSingleItem>
{
    // specialized methods here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Thus, is there a way of creating a list of singleItems derived from an abstract list of abstractItems? I have the feeling this must have been done a thousand times, however I have no idea how to search for it.

Comment: @DanielBencik, what is the value of the abstract list in your scenario? Why not use a `List<QSingleItem>` directly instead?

Comment: i wonder why its passed by value. i thought classes are always passed by reference as default .is this because of abstract?

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: The scenario is that there are more derived classes like QSingleItem, and as a result more than one specialized list. Thats why it pays to offload the common functions to an abstract base.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, nothing to do with the fact is abstract. Parameters (even of reference type) in C# are always by value, unless specified otherwise; but in the case of a reference type, it's a reference that is passed by value. Read this article for more detailed explanations: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: Up until today, I thought so too. However, try the code with 'ref QAbstractItem yItem' and you will see it will not compile. Leaving out the ref was the only thing that made the code compile, and I ran into problems just when I ran it.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: Thanks for the article.

Comment: @DanielBencik, in this case, a better option would be to make the list class generic. Something like `class QItemsList<T> where T : QAbstractItem`.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: The problem with that approach is that there are some functions specific to QItemsList<QSingleItem>, some funtionc specific to QItemsList<QMultiItem> which could only be performed using extensions. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @DanielBencik, in this case you can always inherit from the generic class (e.g. class `QSingleItemsList : QItemsList<QSingleItem>`) and add your specific methods

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: Ah ha!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in that method:

```
public void getFirst(QAbstractItem yItem)
{
    yItem = xItems[0];        // XXX
}
```

You must be aware of that when you pass an argument to a method, copy of the reference to `yItem` is created. So, if you assign new value to `yItem` it has no effect on the actual argument that you passed to method `getFirst`.
According to C# specification, it's proper behavior.

You can consider changing your method to return first element:

```
public QAbstractItem getFirst()
{
    return xItems[0];        // XXX
}
```